# Problems with textbox text changed with C#

Tags: c#, textbox, event-handling

I am having a problem with having the eventhandler textchanged method to work with an array of textboxes. The textboxes are generated through C# and not through ASP.NET.

here is the TextBox code in C#:

```
int i = 1;
foreach(string a in data)
{
    i++;
    TextBox text = new TextBox();
    text.TextChanged += new EventHandler(updateone);
    text.AutoPostBack = true;
    text.ID = Convert.ToString(i);
}
```

I tried out the  Text.AutoPostBack false and true and I had the same result. The updateone method is not even touched when I change the text of the textbox. When I do change the text 
of the textbox it does update the website, but again the updateone method is not even touched in the code. Here is the updateone code:

```
protected void updateone(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox text = (TextBox)sender;
}
```

I thank everyone for their help! I am just confused why this is not working... and also I have to use the C# method and not the ASP.NET way.

Comment: There are a couple strange things to point out here. First, I don't see an array of `TextBox` objects, just a single `Textbox` named text. Secondly, your `updateone` method doesn't do anything. You create a temporary `TextBox` and set it equal to `sender` and then return. Try making a window pop up or something instead.

Comment: sorry I go through a loop creating different textboxes from the same code that is displayed above. Also I did do breakpoints to see if the updateone code was even touched, which it wasn't... I did put stuff in it and it still didn't do anything.

Comment: I updated the question with a loop.

Comment: I don't think your `foreach` loop actually does anything, for the same reason that your `updateone` method doesn't do anything. You create a new `TextBox` object, change its properties, and then it gets destroyed. Are you posting your actual code?

Comment: yes I am, the data is an array of strings that fill the textbox ID and then the textboxes are displayed on the website. I did the same thing but for checkboxes and worked just fine with a eventHandler and executes the eventHandler code perfectly... but for some reason the textboxes do not work the same.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried storing references to your TextBoxes in an instance member so that they don't get garbage collected?

something like:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = ...

//in a loop    
text.ID = Convert.ToString(i);
textBoxes.Add(text);
```

-- edit
also, as a rule of thumb, put as much logging in your application as possible.
Whether it is `NLog`, any other logging tool or even a simple `Console.WriteLine()`, seeing what your code is actually doing is very helpful.

Comment: I did try it and I did set the textboxes in a list and still the same problem happens... I will play around with the code and see what I can do. Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've confirmed that you're posting your actual code and don't seem to get what I'm trying to say, let me try to explain in an answer.

First problem: Your array of `TextBox`es does not exist, which the other answer has already addressed and you've apparently fixed but haven't updated the code in your question to show your fix.

Second problem: The `TextBox`es you create are not being added to your form in any way. I'm not sure how you're testing your event handler without doing that.

Third problem: Your event handler `updateone` doesn't do anything. Imagine you walk into a grocery store, pick up an orange, put it back down, and then leave. That's what your event handler is doing. Instead of just instantiating a temporary `TextBox` and then doing nothing, try making a message box pop up, or changing the text of another control that exists on the form.

Maybe something like this will work:

```
List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>();
int i=1;
foreach(string a in data) // I assume data is a list or array of strings
{
    // I'm not sure why you iterate over data if you don't use it at all inside the loop...
    ++i;
    TextBox text = new TextBox();
    text.TextChanged += new EventHandler(updateone);
    text.AutoPostBack = true;
    text.ID = Convert.ToString(i);
    // Add the TextBox to form here, not sure what the call is
}
Label info = new Label;
Label.Text = "Hello!";
// Add Label to form here, again not sure what the call is
```

And then your event handler:

```
protected void updateone(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    info.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}
```

Comment: I have tried exactly what you just showed up there and it does not even go into the updateone method. I am using asp.net for the textboxes and the textboxes are being shown just perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically creating ASP.NET controls. This means that they will not be automatically re-created on the postback of the form. Also, the controls have to be created in the Page_Init event, not the Page_Load event.

So the question is, where and when are you creating the textboxes. Make sure they are created at the Page_Init stage, and you are creating them in the request and in the postback.